# swap text before and after a character

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a large text file `code.txt` with the following equalities

```
        oReservist.Role = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 2)
        oReservist.Surname = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3)
        oReservist.Name = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4)
        ...
```

I want to change the first part of the equality by the second and the second by the first one. That is to say :

```
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 2) = oReservist.Role
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3) = oReservist.Surname
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4) = oReservist.Name 
        ...
```

How can I handle that ? Until now I can only delete the parts before and after :

```
sed 's/.*=.*//' file
```

Comment: Also asked on [superuser](https://superuser.com/q/1452328/4714). Please don't post a question on multiple sites. You waste people's time when they answer here but there's more appropriate answers elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk` with `" = "` as field separator, and simply turn around the fields.

```
awk -F " = " '{OFS=FS;print $2,$1}' file
```

or using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(.*\) = \(.*\)/\2 = \1/' file
```

(using capture groups `\(...\)` and calling them in the replacement string with `\1` and `\2`)

Both will not eliminate the tab or white space at the beginning of the line.

Output:

```
Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 2) =         oReservist.Role
Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3) =         oReservist.Surname
Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4) =         oReservist.Name
```

---

To keep them, you can capture them somehow, e.g.:

```
sed 's/\([[:blank:]]*\)\(.*\) = \(.*\)/\1\3 = \2/' file
```

or leave out the blanks from the first capture:

```
sed 's/\([^[:blank:]]*\) = \(.*\)/\2 = \1/' file
```

Output:

```
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 2) = oReservist.Role
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3) = oReservist.Surname
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4) = oReservist.Name
```

Comment: Thank uou, that makes sense ! I tried it on my 2009 Windows powershell. Yet it seems that `sed` is not recognised :'(

Comment: That means you need to edit your tags to get more appropriate eyes on your problem. Add the [tag:windows] and [tag:powershell] tags, and remove [tag:sed]

Comment: @pLumo, you can simplify your sed a bit: `'s/([^[:blank:]]+) = (.*)/\2 = \1/'`

Comment: sure, thanks for suggestion, added!

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below 2 methods

python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
m=open('filename','r')
for i in m:
    k=i.strip().split('=')
    fi=k[1]
        la=k[0]
        print "{0}={1}".format(fi,la)
```

output

```
Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 2)=oReservist.Role 
 Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3)=oReservist.Surname 
 Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4)=oReservist.Name
```

Method2

```
awk -F "=" '{print $2"="$1}' y.txt|sed -r "s/\s+//g" 

Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne,2)=oReservist.Role
Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne,3)=oReservist.Surname
Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne,4)=oReservist.Name
```

praveen@praveen:~$